# Semantic React UI controlled components not working with React Final Form

Tags: semantic-ui, semantic-ui-react, react-final-form, final-form, react-final-form-arrays

This question has also been raised on the react-final-form github issues list at https://github.com/final-form/react-final-form/issues/939

I'm using Semantic React UI 2.02 with react-final-form 6.5.3.

**First Issue**

I have a controlled Semantic React UI dropdown on a component that gets its value from the parent. If I put the Dropdown component directly into a React Final Form Field it works as expected. I can clear the currently selected value in the dropdown by updating the state value. But when I use a component you can see it ignores any change the parents tries to make to the state.

Not many examples out there to help guide me unfortunately.

**Second Issue**

Issue was "fixed" in 6.3.1 but still appears to exist.

#544

If I try to pass multiple to a custom component the value is ignored and always false.

Link to sandbox here https://codesandbox.io/s/semantic-react-ui-react-final-form-how-to-clear-dropdown-4l17f?file=/src/index.tsx

**Third Issue**
If you implement a wizard form and use a Semantic React UI dropdown on one of those forms. When you try to move back, the value selected on the dropdown is lost. Can't figure out a way to set it back again.

Would appreciate the wisdom of other users. Thanks in advance.